# How to force desktop version of Facebook on Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, facebook

Until recently, it was possible to select the "Desktop site" tickbox in Chrome on Android, browse to "www.facebook.com" and get the desktop Facebook site. That has stopped working and I now get the mobile site regardless of the "Desktop site" tickbox setting.

Is there a way to ensure I get the desktop version of Facebook on Chrome on an unrooted phone without affecting other sites in other tabs? If not, can this be done with another browser?

Comment: Desktop mode for Facebook (checked on login page only) on Kiwi Browser (Chrome based) is working fine.